# Can Service be both Started and Bound

Tags: android

The official article about Services claims, that Android services can either be Started or Bound. However, I don't see problem overriding both `onStartCommand()` and `onBind()`. The problem is, that this does not seem to work. What I am trying to do is start a Started Service from one Activity, then address that Service through other Activies by binding them to the Service, and, lastly, stopping it like a Started Service. Nevertheless, when I try to bind an Activity to the Service `'bindService()` behaves like it's not actually being called (I checked it by putting a breakpoint on `onBind()` ). Is using Services both the Started and Bound way possible?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html, see "**Binding to a Started Service** As discussed in the Services document, you can create a service that is both started and bound" on the right side

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes,we can call one service for both bound and unbound.

Comment: can u give any example for same, i need to do same...using bind service i need to make it run in background also when app is killed.